# phpでREST API作成

Tags: php, api, rest

phpでREST APIを作成したのですが、GETとDELETEはできるのですが、POSTができずに以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

*エラー*

```html
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in <b>/Users/user_name/php_workspace/sandbox/inquery.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
```

コードは以下のとおりです。

*コード*

```html
  1 <?php
  2 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  3 header("X-Content-Type-Option: nosniff");
  4 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=hoge', 'hoge', 'hoge');
  5 switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
  6   case 'GET':
  7     $st = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM inquery");
  8     echo json_encode($st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
  9     break;
 10   case 'POST':
 11     $in = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
 12     $st = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO inquery(title,body) VALUES(:title,:body)");
 13     $st->execute($in);
 14     break;
 15   case 'DELETE':
 16     $st = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM inquery WHERE id=?");
 17     $st->execute([$_GET['id']]);
 18     break;
 19 }
```

モデルは以下のとおりです。

```html
id(int) primary key
title(varchar)
body(text)
timestamp(timestamp)
```

どこが間違っているか教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESTというよりはPDOの問題で、

```
$st->execute($in);
```

の`$in`が正しい形式の配列になっていないのだと思います。
`$in`の中身が分かりませんが、以下のような連想配列でパラメーターを渡してください。

```
$st->execute(array(':title' => $in['title'], ':body' => $in['body']));
```